# Circle Image View not showing up

Tags: android, gradle

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

**Added and Synced in Dependencies the below code:**

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
```

see the below picture for the problem.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17yYcUBQFQr0NiykBtEfCISBI4fMWT1vM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`CircleImageView`**](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
```

**XML**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/add_icon"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong line. I added <implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'>

Comment: @MahmudulHasan add `android:src="@drawable/"`

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I used "background" instead of "src" that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your gradle

```
 dependencies {
      ...
      implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
  }
```

xml be like

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

for more info about this library visit in :https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Google has released `ShapeableImageView` which provides wide range of shapes.
No need to use 3rd party libraries now.

To work with `ShapeableImageView` in your android project, you need to add dependency material design library.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Define a style in your styles.xml

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

and last add this shapeableImageView in your xml.

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
    />
```

now only circle you can create different shapes on imageview with right styling.